# what size are wallet photos when using file explorer print program?

Tags: printing, photos

I'm using windows 10's file explorer. I want to print some photos in "wallet size", and I know HOW to do it, but I don't know exactly how big "wallet size" is. I googled it and the internet says it's around 2.5"x3.5". Is this right? Help?

Answer (score 1):

In the Windows 10 Photo app, when printing, when you select "Wallet" it says **2x3 in.**:

[image]

Using **Share** > **Print** in File Explorer, Wallet Prints measure **2.5" x 4.25"**.

Of course, this will also depend on the ratio of your image. 2.5" x 4.25" is the maximum space allocated to a Wallet print. If your image is not that exact ratio, its dimensions will differ.